# Sklearn SimpleImputer strategy constant vs Pandas fillna?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

What is the difference of using sklearn SimpleImputer strategy constant and using fillna(value)?
For example:  `SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant', fill_value = 0)` vs `df.fillna(0)`
Even for strategy = mean, we can just use `df.fillna(df.mean)`.
With simpleImputer, we still need to fit_transform the dataframe and more lines.
fillna is short code.
What is the case when we need to use simpleImputer than fillna? Is simpleImputer faster?

Comment: this is the same functionality implemented in two different packages - you can use them interchangeably.  A marginal benefit of the imputer is that it can be swapped out exactly for some other kind of imputer with less change to your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that when you are trying to deploy a model, it's cleaner to have a pipeline of transformations on dataset using sklearn. You could even add all the transformations on your dataset, before training or inference, in a nice pipeline wrapper, such as a [`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) object. If you use an `sklearn` implementation, it's easier to integrate and debug later.

Answer (score 0):

I think: Both are for filling missing values. If `pandas` is not used in the project, `SimpleImputer` can be a good option as it is a built-in `sklearn` feature.

- [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#) has better options like `median` and `most-frequent`
- `df.fillna()` is most common used, can be used in complicated scenarios.

- not tested performance-wise

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the answer will depend on the challenge that you are facing.

.fillna() is a method that you can use for visual data exploratory and explanatory. But when you plan to predict values using Machine Learning, SimpleImputer() is a better choice.

Why? Because all the code before and after the SimpleImputer() help you to prevent data leakage.

If before splitting data you identify missing values on your target, use .fillna() on that column, and SimpleImputer() for your features after splitting with your best strategy choice.

Keep in mind to evaluate the "weight" of the missing values (ALWAYS). If before splitting is less than 1% in a data set smaller than 1,000 rows, maybe just drop it (only on your target). The impact of the missing data will guide you.

Again, if you are creating a prediction model, a SimpleImputer inside a ColumnTransformer would be a robust choice to address missing data.

Have a great one,

Ed.